# After I input 'yo code', the option info cannot be displayed except an icon

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, yeoman-generator

I follow the steps of https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension, after installing `node.js` and `yeoman`, I input `$ yo code` in the shell, but can only see an icon without any option information.

The expected CLI is as follows but I cannot see tips like `What type of extension do you want to create?` ( Temporarily I cannot insert an image, sorry)

```
[icon] Welcome to the Visual Studio Code Extension generator!

? What type of extension do you want to create? < Use arrow keys>
> New Extension <TypeScript>
> New Extension <JavaScript>
> New Color Theme
> New Language Support
> New Code Snippets
...
```

I reinstalled `yeoman` and `$ npm install -g yo generator-code` but in vain. Has anyone experienced this problem or had an idea? Thank you very much!

```
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.4
yeoman's version: 2.0.6
Vscode'v version: 1.33.1 (1.33.1)
```

Comment: Did you try waiting a minute or two? For me there is a large delay between typing `yo code` and getting any output.

Comment: Hi, HolyBlackCat, the icon appeared immediately after I typed `yo code` but after 4 minutes, nothing else appeared.

Answer (score 0):

For me waiting for ~ 2 minutes has helped to resolve the issue.

After that time following message was printed

`Unable to fetch latest vscode version: Error: [object Object]`

and then the questions appeared.